# Upload tar.gz file to S3 Bucket with Boto3 and Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am unable to load a tar.gz file from my local directory to an S3 bucket location. I've had no issues running the function below to upload any csv files but am getting the error: "Fileobj must implement read" error. I am using Boto3 and Python

The tar_file is the file on my local drive to upload to the S3 bucket location

```
import csv
import glob
import os
import tarfile
from datetime import date
from typing import Optional, Set
from io import BytesIO

import psycopg2
import boto3

from constants import (
    ARTIFACT_STORE,
    DB_HOST,
    DB_PASSWORD,
    DB_USER,
    EXCLUDED_TABLES,
    NIPR_DB_NAME,
    S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    S3_ENDPOINT_URL,
    BUCKET_NAME
)

def upload_s3_file():
    tar_file = f"{ARTIFACT_STORE}/{date.today()}_cds.tar.gz"
    s3 = boto3.client('s3',endpoint_url=S3_ENDPOINT_URL,aws_access_key_id=S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,aws_secret_access_key=S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    with tarfile.open(tar_file,'r:gz') as tar:
        s3.upload_fileobj(tar,BUCKET_NAME,tar_file)
```

When I run the below function on a csv generated file to the S3 bucket, I have no issues:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3',endpoint_url=S3_ENDPOINT_URL,aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
with open("test.csv", "rb") as f:
        s3.upload_fileobj(f,BUCKET_NAME, "test")
```

Comment: I think you should just use ```with open(tar_file, 'rb') as tar:```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're supposed to pass a file object to `upload_fileobj` and not a tarfile object.

```
with open(tar_file,'rb') as tar:
    s3.upload_fileobj(tar,BUCKET_NAME,tar_file)
```